# Unable to delete file in Centos

Tags: linux, centos, bash

I can't remove certain file in Linux. Here the example:

```
[root@HBL01 home]# ls -ltira index.php 
393591 -r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 14335 Nov 23  2021 index.php

[root@HBL01 home]# rm -rf index.php
```

The file exists:

```
[root@HBL01 home]# ls -ltira index.php 
393591 -r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 14335 Nov 24  2021 index.php

[root@HBL01 home]# lsattr index.php
--------------e----- index.php
```

I try to write something with *vim* but appears at the end this message:

`"index.php" [readonly] 17L, 14335C`

Tried to change the permisos but... not run correctly:

```
[root@HBL01 ]# chmod 777 index.php 

[root@HBL01 ]# ls -ltra index.php 
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 8230 Nov 23  2021 index.php
```

I try to remove the file (no output) but the fie persists.

```
[root@HBL01]# lsattr  index.php
--------------e----- index.php

[root@HBL01]# rm -rf index.php

[root@HBL01]# ls -ltrh index.php
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 8.1K Dec 11  2021 index.php

[root@HBL01]# fuser index.php

[root@HBL01]# ls -ld index.php
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 8211 Dec 11  2021 index.php
```

What exactly happend? How can I remove this file?

Thanks in advance!

---

Problem persists:

```
[root@HBL01]# lsattr  index.php
--------------e----- index.php

[root@HBL01]# rm -rf index.php

[root@HBL01]# ls -ltrh index.php
-r--r--r-- 1 apache apache 8.1K Dec 11  2021 index.php
```

Comment: Stop using `rm -rf`.  Really.  The `-f` option tells rm that you don't care about errors and don't want to know.  If you omit that option, you'll find out why it can't delete it.  If you are not happy with the answers you've gotten so far, modify your question to include the error that `-f` suppresses.

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory? Is the disk mounted read-write or read-only? Is the file local or on nfs? If nfs - what are export permissions?

Comment: the file not's on NFS. The directory have a correct permisions because another files on the same directory can be removed.

Comment: The timestamp before and after the removal is different (23rd versus 24th of Nov). Is it possible that there is some process running which recreates the file? And why does it show year 2021? Try `lsof index.php` (possibly as root) to see if there is any process keeping it open.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

chattr -i index.php;
rm -rf index.php

Comment: executed but have the same issue. No output. No error. I can't remove the file

Answer (score 0):

Is the file writable, it doesn't appear so? chmod +w index.php and then rm -rf index.php OR in one (pastable) step;

chmod +w index.php; rm -rf index.php

If no result, try creating a file in this same directory, and then performing an ls -al, and then consequently deleting the newly created file.  This can be achieved as follows:

touch filename01.tmp; ls -al filename01.tmp; rm filename01.tmp

Give it a shot and let me know how it goes.  If no go, please paste any output the 2nd command provides.  It should give a listing of the filename01.tmp file you create. We can possibly learn something by doing this that will lead to an solution.